# MySQL query - limit function

Tags: mysql, limit

I'm using the below query to get datas from mysql database.

```
select component,count(component) as Quantity from mfgGroup where 
 period between '2013-01-01' and '2013-12-31'
```

I'm getting almost 100+ rows as a result.

Now i want to display only top 25 components.so I modified the query as below

```
select component,count(component) as Quantity from mfgGroup where 
period between '2013-01-01' and '2013-12-31' limit 0,25
```

But i what i need is to display the top 25 items and rest of the components should be tagged as 'Others' with the quantity numbers.

Like these below in the resultset.

```
Item1 123
Item2 112
....
....
Item25 24
Others 156
```

Comment: What is `156` in the `Others` line? Is it the number of other rows?

Comment: yeah, the rest of the components number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT component, COUNT(*) AS Quantity
FROM mfgGroup
WHERE period between '2013-01-01' and '2013-12-31'
GROUP BY component
ORDER BY Quantity DESC
LIMIT 25

UNION

SELECT 'Others', COUNT(*) c
FROM mfgGroup g
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT component, COUNT(*) AS Quantity
    FROM mfgGroup
    WHERE period between '2013-01-01' and '2013-12-31'
    GROUP BY component
    ORDER BY Quantity DESC
    LIMIT 25
) top25
ON g.component = top25.component
WHERE top25.component IS NULL
AND period between '2013-01-01' and '2013-12-31'
HAVING C > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using row_number also.

```
SELECT component,sum(quantity) FROM(
SELECT @rn:=@rn+1 AS rank, IF(@rn>25,"Others",component) component, Quantity
FROM (
    SELECT component, COUNT(*) AS Quantity
    FROM mfgGroup
    WHERE period between '2013-01-01' and '2013-12-31'
    GROUP BY component
    ORDER BY Quantity DESC
) t1, (SELECT @rn:=0) t2
) temp
GROUP BY component
```